Disclosing account information from one firm to another
I have managed accounts in Schwab and Vanguard.
My Vanguard personal advisor wants to know my Schwab account information in order to use a tool on my Vanguard account. Is it ok to give him the Schwab account details?

What kind of account details are you talking about? Balances? Allocations? Login credentials?

You would need to add a lot more detail: What tool does he want to use and why does that tool require access to Schwab. What account info and what level of access? Is the advisor authorized to transact on your behalf, what exactly does the advisor do for you? There are circumstance under which this is a perfectly legitimate request, but others where that would be definitely NOT ok.

Yes. He sells and buys funds on my behalf. If he sells a fund in my account , he wants to make sure that the other firm does not buy the same fund within 30 days. This is the reason he wants to know the other account info.

I gave my advisor the information and permission that lets them view my balances in semi-real-time, but no access to move money out of or between those accounts.
If you aren't sure you trust the instructions you are getting from your advisor to do that, you can ask your bank to sanity check them for you.
Or you can simply tell the advisor "no. I'll give you current balances when I want updated advice." Which is, of course, how these services used to operate before network services became ubiquitous
